# Global WP variable only exists when called outside of cron

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have been using a global variable from a WordPress plugin to send data to an external source, and the plugin is responsible for handling the API calls.

This plugin has no methods to get the instance of the variable, but instead instantiates the class in a variable just after the class definition (see below).

```
$cronvar=new cronvar();
$cronvar->instance();
```

I have been able to use this global object to interact with the methods from the plugin programatically, as I am trying to reproduce certain actions using a cron job.

```
global $cronvar;
```

The problem is that when running the job manually, such as on a page load or if I activate the cron job via an interface such as WP Crontrol or the CLI, the function runs as expected, and the global variable is found, but when running automatically, the global doesn't exist.

If the cron job is running automatically, I have confirmed that the function is running, but the global that I have been using is null. I can't see why the same code wouldn't work via cron when run automatically vs when manually triggered, but there has to be some difference in scope or loading of plugins that I'm missing, and I'm unable to interact with the plugin without this global variable. The server has WP_CRON disabled and uses a script to load wp-cron every minute.

Is there a different or better method that I should be using, or am I missing something with the automatic scheduling?

Comment: a. make sure "global $cronvar;" is executed before the object created. 
b. make sure that all library needed is loaded. you may use get_included_files  the use print_r and die to simply print and halt the process

Answer (score 1):

Many plugins only load code (using require_once or similar code-loading statements) when they know they're running in an admin page. Something like this.

```php
if ( is_admin() ) {
  require_once whatever;
}
```

So the code doesn't get loaded for a plain old cronjob, or REST API call, or even a front-end page rendering.  This reduces the plugin's overhead, so it's generally a good idea.

But in your case your cronjob needs code from that other plugin that didn't load. You'll need to load it yourself inside your cronjob code. (You didn't tell us what plugin so it's hard to give you more specific advice.)